# HREF is not working in ion-slide

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am trying to put href link to slider images and text in ion-slide.

Here is the code of mine.

```html
<ion-slide-box ng-show="!cloading">
  <ion-slide ng-repeat="img in simgs">
    <div class="box">
      <a ng-href="#/menu/tab/featured-post/{{post.id}}" style="text-decoration:none;">
        <img src="{{img.url}}" ></img>
        <p class="prodblk2" ng-href="#/menu/tab/featured-post/{{post.id}}" >
          {{img.title}}           
        </p>
       </a>
     </div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

The link is appearing, but its not working when I click on it. I guess, the ion-slider properties like sliding or dragging overriding the mouse actions.
I tried ng-href and even ng-click by adding some JS function.

I hope nothing wrong about the code. I think, I need to add some property to the ion-slide tag.
I searched for similar questions but I haven't found. If anybody knows it please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I end up with the same problem as you, my solution was to use ng-click on the ion-slide directive, because in there it will fire up.

So you can create a method, pass the id's you need as parameters and then handle the route in the controller. Here's my solution for your problem:

HTML:

```
<ion-slide-box ng-show="!cloading">
<ion-slide ng-repeat="img in simgs" ng-click="slideClick({{post.id}})">
<div class="box">
  <a style="text-decoration:none;">enter code here
    <img src="{{img.url}}" ></img>
    <p class="prodblk2 >
      {{img.title}}           
    </p>
   </a>
 </div>
```

Then create some method on your controller using $location to go to your URL.

JS:

```
$scope.slideClick = function(postId) {
    $location.path("/menu/tab/featured-post/" + postId);
}
```